# change value of local variable from function inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have something like this:

```
def a():
  #do something
  foo = 0
  def b():
    foo += 2
    # do something
  b()
  #do something

a()
```

but it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    a()
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 7, in a
    b()
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in b
    foo += 2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

How can I access `foo` without making it global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment to `foo` in `b` makes it a local variable, unrelated to the variable of the same name in `a`. Use the `nonlocal` statement to change that.

```
def a():
    #do something
    foo = 0
    def b():
        nonlocal foo
        foo += 2
        # do something
    b()
  #do something
```

Now `foo` in `b` is the same variable as `foo` in `a`. `nonlocal` is like `global`, but uses the closest enclosing scope that contains the name `foo` rather than jumping straight to the global scope.